# DragMove prevent preview mouse up

Tags: c#, wpf, drag

I have an application that I want to move the window the problem is that all images that had a preview mouse up now are not working.

This is the windo event:

```
 private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     DragMove();
 }
```

and this is the image event:

```
 private void image1_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("WTF IS WPF?");
 }
```

If I remove the DragMove function the image event works.

Comment: What does image1_PreviewMouseUp do, exactly?

Comment: Its the previewmouseup event of an image, in this example I just want to show a message, in my application y use the previewmousedown event to do some tasks and the previewmouseup to do other tasks, the problem is that the previewmouseup doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why execute DragMove() all the time?

```
MouseButtonState _mouseButtonState;
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _mouseButtonState = e.ButtonState;
}

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(_mouseButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        DragMove();
}
```

I would also put a check in image1_PreviewMouseUp

```
private void image1_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(_dragging) return;

    //else do your preview
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it gave me an exception but I changed the condition of Window_MouseMove to `if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.pressed) ...` and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I ran into the same situation and was implementing a method of checking the initial down pos with the next pos on mouse move... and this is much more elegant. Why not check button state in the MouseMove method without MouseDown though? "if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) { this.DragMove(); }" ?

Comment: you're right, you can do that directly in the MouseMove. I probably got "boxed in" with the question methods...

Comment: I was there too and noticed the option of doing that way. Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something and that it would still work that way. Thanks for answering this. ;) Much better than my old method.